# How can I recursively find all files in current and subfolders based on regular expressions

Tags: regex, linux, bash, find

I need to find all files with names matching different regular expressions in directories and subdirectories and print info about them.

For example, I have 3 directories:

```sh
/foo1
/foo1/foo2
/foo1/foo2/foo3
```

Files in this directories `fgg1_1` `fgg2_1` `fgg3_1`:

```sh
/foo1/fgg1_1
/foo1/foo2/fgg2_1
/foo1/foo2/foo3/fgg3_1
```

And I need to find all files matching RE `'f.+1$'`. One might think to use

```sh
find /foo -regex 'f.+1$' -printf '%f %A@ %s \n'
```

but shurely it woun't match anything, because -regex evaluates full filenames e.g. `/foo1/foo2/fgg2_1`.

I tried to grep the output, but it didn't help much since I still need to get info about files I find

```sh
find /foo -print '%f\n' | grep 'f.+1$'
```

It's important to note, that I'm looking for a somewhat universal solution since this command is executed on the remote host through ssh and compiled using python script, thus paths and RE's for file names can be different every time

#### Solution

You'll need to strip all `^` symbols from the beginning of filename's REs

```sh
find /foo -regex '.*\/f.+1$' -printf '%p %f %h %Y %G %U %A@ %C@ %T@ %s\n'
```

A bit of overkill, but I ended up using this because of how `stat` displays c_time

```sh
find /foo | grep -e '.*\/f.+1$' | xargs stat --printf '%n %F %g %u %X %Z %Y %s %A\n'
```

Comment: So, would you accept a Python script as solution or only shell?

Comment: a space is missing between `'f.+1$'` and `-print` also `-print` doesn't have argument but `-printf`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To match whole paths that end in a filename matching a given regular expression, you could prepend `.*/` to it, for example `.*/f.+1$`. The `.*/` should match the path preceding the filename.

Comment: Just figured that one myself a few hours ago. I had to strip `^` at the beginning of filenames because the same effect is achieved by putting RE just after `.*/`

Also ended up using
`find /foo -maxdepth 2  | grep -e '.*\/f.+1$' |  xargs stat --printf '%n %F %g %u %X %Z %Y %s %A\n'
`

Answer (score 0):

if you dont need regex you could try :

> find /foo -name "fgg*" | xargs ls -l